# Unable to find an entry point named 'sk_color_get_bit_shift' in DLL 'libSkiaSharp'. when using SkiaSharp 15.9.1

Tags: c#, skiasharp, skia

I am attempting to build and use the MicoCharts project available here: https://github.com/dotnet-ad/Microcharts which is dependant on this SkiaSharp project available here: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp

The specific version I am attempting to use is 15.9.1 (the version that the nuget package downloads) which utilizes skia m59.

I need to build them myself and cannot use Nuget due to business restrictions, just use the package isn't an option for me.

I have built skia m59, SkiaSharp and MicroCharts but when I attempt to create a SKBitmap object I get an error when it attempts to initialize SkiaSharp.SKImageInfo. The error is as follows:

**Unable to find an entry point named 'sk_color_get_bit_shift' in DLL 'libSkiaSharp'.**

I had to make a few changes to the base BUILD.gn to point to the correct file locations, for the windows SDK and the VC install. I enabled skia_use_gdi in the BUILD.gn and ran the following commands.

```
python2 tools/git-sync-deps

gn gen out/Release --args="is_debug=false is_official_build=true skia_use_system_expat=false skia_use_system_libjpeg_turbo=false skia_use_system_libpng=false skia_use_system_libwebp=false skia_use_system_zlib=false skia_use_icu=false is_component_build=true"

ninja -C out/Release skia
```

This process outputs a DLL I *assumed* is the same as the libSkiaSharp that the SkiaSharp project relies on. I add all my references and run, the project runs successfully until I attempt to create the SkBitmap object then it fails.

Either this DLL is not the correct DLL and I am misunderstanding something here or something in my process is wrong. I would love any help I can get as I am completely new to building these sorts of projects, I am a C# developer by trade.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the same thing. SkiaSharp has a few other bits that it adds to the core skia. The output that you would have got is a skia.dll, which only part. Not sure how you got a `libSkiaSharp` from the `skia` target...

If you can't use SkiaSharp from NuGet.org (which is the supported case) you can follow this to build your own: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/wiki/Building-SkiaSharp

You can also check out the Azure DevOps yaml: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/blob/master/scripts/azure-pipelines.yml

Just set up your own DevOps job to use that and all the work will be done for you.